# SVN: How to migrate a working copy after dumping and loading to another repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have two SVN repositories *RepoA* and *RepoB*, as well as a working copy of *RepoA* stored in my local machine at "C:\RepoA" that has some uncommitted modifications.  I've just gone through the process of dumping *RepoA* and loading it into *RepoB/NewRepoA*, so now *RepoB/NewRepoA* is equivalent to the root of *RepoA*, with all of the revisions from *RepoA* added into the history of *RepoB*.

Now, I would like to take my working copy of *RepoA* and "migrate" it to *RepoB/NewRepoA*.  Is there any way I can do this and still keep my uncommitted modifications?  The end result should be that the files in my working copy at "C:\RepoA" are unchanged, but the modifications that I've made now affect the files in *RepoB/NewRepoA* when I decide to commit them.

Thanks in advance.  I'm currently using TortoiseSVN 1.9.5 with the relevant SVN command line utilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to check out a new working copy and copy your uncommitted changes into it.

If the repository root URL had changed (and you maintained the same UUID when migrating the repository), `svn relocate`would work for you.

If only the path inside the repository had changed, `svn switch` would work.

But it sounds like neither of the above is true.

Comment: Thanks, that was about the answer I was expecting.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious before I went through with a copy-paste solution